# HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error (после добавления модуля в ASP)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

После добавление модуля в Web.config в ASP.MVC:

```
<httpModules>
      <add name="AuthHttpModule" type="WebUI.Global.Auth.AuthHttpModule" />
</httpModules>
```

выходит сообщение:

> HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

добавьте этот код в `web.config`

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Подробнее: [HTTP Error 500.22](http://www.codingdefined.com/2014/08/http-error-50022-internal-server-error.html)